# Call same function in window ready and window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 different functions to call based on the size of the screen. I call them in ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var $window_width = $(window).width();

    if ($window_width < 768) {
        faq_mobile();
    } else {
        faq();
    }
});
```

But again I want call them on window resize event since the functions are not called then. So I wrote this:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
    window.resizeEvt;
    $(window).resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(window.resizeEvt);
        window.resizeEvt = setTimeout(function() {
            if ($(window).width() < 768) {
                faq_mobile();
            } else {
                faq();  
            }
        }, 250);
    });
});
```

But this does not work properly since the functions faq and faq_mobile have been called multiple times when I resize the window. What is the best solution for on this case?

Comment: It is good to have a debounce as you currently have. `if(window.resizeEvt){clearTimeout(window.resizeEvt);}` you should wrap it within the condition else it will throw error. check console logs.

Comment: Just put your code in a separate function and then set that function as both the resize event handler and the ready event handler!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks a little strange. Consider this example

```js
var isMobileView = false;
var isDesktopView = false;

function handleView(width) {

    if (width < 768 && isDesktopView) {
    
        faq_mobile();
        isMobileView = true;
        isDesktopView = false;
        
    } else if (width >= 768 && isMobileView) {
    
        faq();
        isMobileView = false;
        isDesktopView = true;
        
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var width = $(window).width();
  handleView(width)
  
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  
  var width = $(window).width();
  handleView(width)

})
```

Comment: Yeah the code is a bit messy. Thanks for mentioning that. But your solution does not fix my problem.

Comment: I don't understand the question first time. I've edited my answer. This should work

Answer (score 0):

```
function handler() {        // separate the code and wrap it in a function
    var $window_width = $(window).width();

    if ($window_width < 768) {
        faq_mobile();
    } else {
        faq();
    }
}

$(handler);                 // on load of the document

$(window).resize(handler);  // on resize of the window
```

If you want to keep the delay of the resize event, then change the last line above to this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    window.clearTimeout(window.resizeEvt);     // remove previous delay if any
    window.resizeEvt = setTimeout(function() { // create a new delay
        handler();
        window.resizeEvt = 0;
    }, 250);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. thanks everyone for help. I googled it a bit and found a fix for it. I had to unbind the events which were added inside faq and faq_mobile functions after a resize is done. Then call those functions again. Here is the modified code: (Thanks @disstruct for your advice).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    handleView(width);
});

$(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
    window.resizeEvt;
    $(window).resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(window.resizeEvt);
        window.resizeEvt = setTimeout(function() {
            // here i am unbinding the click events which were previously added inside faq and faq_mobile functions.
            $('.faq-expand, .answer-close').off('click');
            var width = $(window).width();
            handleView(width);
        }, 250);
    });
});

function handleView(width) {
    if (width < 768) {
        faq_mobile();
    } else {
        faq();
    }
}
```